# libraryDependencies for `TFNerDLGraphBuilder()` for Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nlp, sbt, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

Can anyone tell what is libraryDependencies for `TFNerDLGraphBuilder()` for Spark with Scala? It gives me error, `Cannot resolve symbol TFNerDLGraphBuilder`

I see it works for notebook as given below

`https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-workshop/blob/master/tutorials/Certification_Trainings/Public/4.NERDL_Training.ipynb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow graphs in Spark NLP are built using TF python api. As far as I know, the java version for creating the Conv1D/BiLSTM/CRC graph is not included.

So, you need to create it first following the instructions in:

https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/training#tensorflow-graphs

That will create a pb TensorFlow file that you have to include in the NerDLApproach annotator. For example:

```
val nerTagger = new NerDLApproach()
  .setInputCols("sentence", "token", "embeddings")
  .setOutputCol("ner")
  .setLabelColumn("label")
  .setMaxEpochs(100)
  .setRandomSeed(0)
  .setPo(0.03f)
  .setLr(0.2f)
  .setDropout(0.5f)
  .setBatchSize(100)
  .setVerbose(Verbose.Epochs)
  .setGraphFolder(TfGrpahPath)
```

Note that you have to include the embedding annotation first and that the training process will be executed in the driver. It is not distributed as it could be with [BigDL](https://bigdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).